# Error in loading Party package of R

Tags: r

I am trying to install package named *partykit* in R but everytime i try to install i get below error

```
install.packages("partykit")
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/ckingshuk/Documents/R/win-library/3.3’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.3/partykit_1.1-1.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 1231797 bytes (1.2 MB)
downloaded 1.2 MB

Error in install.packages : cannot open file 'C:/Users/ckingshuk/Documents/R/win-library/3.3/file1f88479a12e2/partykit/doc/constparty.pdf': Permission denied
```

I get the same error even for *party* package. I have been using R for almost 6 months and never faced with this kind of permission error earlier for any other packages.

Can anyone help me regarding this error?

Comment: Looks more like a Windows permission problem. (I don't think the decision-tree or data-science tags are useful.) Have you searched SO on the "stem" of  error message? Surely this is a beginner user error.

Comment: Other packages works fine for me and i have been using it for 6 months by now so this kind of error i never faced before